# No module named pafy

Tags: python, pafy

I have installed 'pafy' using pip, when I run this code:

```
import pafy
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evzcGBdEMTQ&ab_channel=orbitron'
dvideo = pafy.new(url)

reso = dvideo.getbest()

reso.download()
```

it gives me this error:

```
No module named 'pafy'
```

when I check in cmd if pafy is installed or not, it says yes. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your ide, or installing the module directly from your ide.

Comment: Answers like these should be in the comment section, because it is not an answer; rather, it is a suggestion.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow sorry if I caused any confusion :)

Comment: I have restarted my vscode and I have restarted my pc but there is no change

Comment: What ide are you using

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

From the official doc, just go with

`pip install pafy`

Source: https://pypi.org/project/pafy/

If you already installed it before, try `pip uninstall pafy` then install it again.

Note: In case you have more than one Python interpreter. Please make sure you are installed it in the right Python interpreter.

You can use

`your_python_path/python -m pip install pafy`

to make it installed in the right Python.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. What do you mean by my python path? Do you mean where it is installed in? Also, I have installed python from Microsoft Store So should I have installed it from their website?

Comment: I am not sure about that, I am not yet try install Python in Microsoft Store. Python should be stored in the disk. This link may help https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor see on the answer section

Comment: Something like this `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe -m pip install pafy`

Comment: Yes it's installed in the same path in my device and I wrote this but no change

Comment: is there log in the cmd?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question, what is log in

Comment: Is there something happen after you type and enter the line above? Maybe a success or error log?

Comment: It says it's installed successfully